# cljs/core.cljs [line 988, col 14] No reader function for tag Inf

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to launch the latest stable `[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.946"]`, using `boot-cljs` and getting this error: `cljs/core.cljs [line 988, col 14] No reader function for tag Inf`.

I've learned that `1.9.946` introduced new `##Inf` syntax: https://cljs.github.io/api/syntax/Inf. but not sure why I'm getting this error. I've also tried to do this: `[adzerk/boot-cljs "2.1.4" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojurescript]]` but it changed nothing.

**Edit:** just tried to build cljs version from repo and hooked up npm deps with `lein-npm`, server rendering of react worked as expected. May be something to do with `boot-cljs` deps or some other my components.

Comment: what version of clojure itself are you using?

Comment: thanks! updated the question. as **jeaye** from #clojurescript@freenode pointed out, there is a bug with clojure alpha2 version, but I'm using clojure 1.8.0 in both cases

Comment: `##Inf` got added to Clojure 1.9 - i'd be surprised, if that is supposed to work with 1.8.

Answer (score 5):

Support for `##Inf` was added in [`tools.reader`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.reader) 1.1.0, which ClojureScript 1.9.946 depends upon.

If you see this error, it is because you have `tools.reader` 1.0.6 or earlier on your classpath.

Note that, while ClojureScript 1.9.946 specifies `[org.clojure/tools.reader "1.1.0"]` as a dependency, explicitly specifying an older version in your project configuration would cause the issue.

Also note that this is independent of the Clojure version being used. If desired, you can run the ClojureScript 1.9.946 compiler using Clojure 1.8.0 and successfully compile ClojureScript code that makes use of `##Inf`; Clojure 1.9.0 is not required.